# Hover issue using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three products. I am displaying the last product active on page load. If I hover on other product then the active class will assign to the product.

Now My issue is,

1) I have to remove the `New product` text from the third product when hovering on the one or two product if hover on the third then displays the `New Product` again.

2) If I directly hover on the first product then active class not removing from the third product.

When my page load.(It's correct output)
[image]

When I directly hover on product one. (It should remove from the product third)
[image]

Notice here, I hover on product one but product three is showing `New Product` text. I have to remove that.
[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $('.products.onloadhover').addClass('product_set_hover');
});
$(".products").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("product_set_hover");
  }
);
```

```css
.products {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 250px;
}

.products h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.new_products {
  background-color: #fbc60e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new_products span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}

.product_set_hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: #d76223;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products onloadhover">
      <div class="new_products"><span>New products</span></div>
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this : when a product elementt is hover remove background from all "product_set_hover" elements and hide "new_products" and then add the background to the current element and show "new_products" if exist

```js
$(function() {
  $('.products.onloadhover').addClass('product_set_hover');
});
$(".products").hover(
  function() {
    $(".product_set_hover").removeClass("product_set_hover");
    $(".new_products").hide();
    $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
    $(this).find(".new_products").show();
  }
);
```

```css
.products {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 250px;
}

.products h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.new_products {
  background-color: #fbc60e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new_products span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}

.product_set_hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: #d76223;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products onloadhover">
      <div class="new_products"><span>New products</span></div>
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bcv9prj6/

Comment: @Mustapha, Please check the jsfiddle showing the different code and output

Comment: I changed the fiddle link

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch, Yes, your code is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way,

1. Hide `new_products` explicitly and show if  active `Products` div has class `new_product`.

   ```
   $("div.new_products").hide();
   $("div.product_set_hover div.new_products").show();
   ```
2. Remove `product_set_hover` explicitly, which will remove the last active and then assign it back to the active `Products` div.

   ```
   $("div.product_set_hover").removeClass("product_set_hover");
   $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
   ```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.products.onloadhover').addClass('product_set_hover');
});
$(".products").hover(
function(){
   
   $("div.product_set_hover").removeClass("product_set_hover");
   $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
   
   $("div.new_products").hide();
   $("div.product_set_hover div.new_products").show();
   
 }
);
```

```css
.products {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.products h2 {
  font-size: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.new_products {
  background-color: #fbc60e;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.new_products span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
}

.product_set_hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  background-color: #d76223;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products">
    <div class="new_products"><span>New products</span></div>
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="products onloadhover">
      <div class="new_products"><span>New products</span></div>
      <h2>Products1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will show the "new products" label for all products that have one. Not just for the one that is hovered.

Comment: @Gerard, That piece of code will execute against the hovered product and `$(this)` will get executed only on the active product

Comment: Add the "new products" div for the first product and then hover it. It will appear for product 1 and product 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".products").hover(
  function() {
    $('.products').removeClass("product_set_hover");
    $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
  },
);
```

Try this.

Comment: Give me time to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be good - but it needs some tweaks. You need to remove the class when added that's the main idea

Here comes the hasClass() function where you can check whether the class is available or not if so remove it that might solve your problem

And you need to remove the span of new products whenever you hover the boxes

```
    $(function() {
          $(".products").hover(
            function() {
                 $(".new_products").hide();
                 if($(this).hasClass("product_set_hover")){
                      $(this).removeClass("product_set_hover");
                  }
                  else{
                   $(this).addClass("product_set_hover");
                  }
            });
        });
```